# Web Api hosted on IIS 7.5 with routing parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi developed in VS2012 MVC 4 WebApi. It works great when run locally on IISExpress from VS. However, once I deploy to IIS 7.5 IIS does not seem to understand the parameters in the uri.
WebApiConfig.cs routing looks lie this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "CourseOffering",
routeTemplate: "course/courseoffering/{schoolcode}/{markingperiod}/{schoolyear}",
defaults: new { controller = "courseoffering", schoolyear = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

and this uri works on IIS Express: `http://localhost:4600/course/courseoffering/3167/s2`

I make a new site on IIS called PPS.Api.Course, when I browse to it (`http://localhost:85/PPS.Api.Course`) I get the expected "Welcome to ASP.NET Web API!" page. However, when I browse to  `http://localhost:85/PPS.Api.Course/course/courseoffering/3167/s2` (and i've tried `http://myservername:85/PPS.Api.course/course/courseoffering/3167/s2`) I get an error "Unable to download s2 from localhost. Unable to open this Internet site."
How can I fix my route and/or IIS to get the parameters in the uri to be recognized?

Answer (score 1):

If you hosted it on IIS you site should be just:

```
http://localhost:85/
```

Thefore based on your routing template:

```
"course/courseoffering/{schoolcode}/{markingperiod}/{schoolyear}"
```

Your *Web Api URL* should be like this:

```
http://localhost:85/course/courseoffering/3167/s2
```